# Как получить доступ к DOM в iframe используя javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Подгружаю в `<iframe>` другой сайт(домены разные), как получить доступ к к элементам страницы? Нажать кнопку например/заменить текст на кнопке и т.д.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

[Подробности на learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes)

Не забывайте о [кросс доменности](https://learn.javascript.ru/iframes#%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: В отладчике internet explorer пишет отказано в доступе при вызове," var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;"

Comment: iframe Вашего сайта?

Comment: нет, iframe стороннего сайта, пробовал с помощью Curl спарсить, не выходит. А если через мозилу заходить на этотм сайт пишет  :"SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP" и "использует защитную технологию, которая является устаревшей и уязвимой для атаки. Злоумышленник может легко выявить информацию, которая, как вы думали, находится в безопасности.". Так что работает только в Iexplorer.

Comment: Прочитайте о кросс доменности. ссылку приложил. Нельзя же любую страницу добавить себе на сайт и делать с ней что захочется

Comment: То есть полный доступ будет к окну только если они с одного доменного имени. Понятно, спасибо. Это политика браузера? разве нельзя как-то обойти это?

Comment: @Batan112, можно попробовать найти галочку в настройках браузера, либо договориться о способе коммуникации с разработчиками сайта вставленного в iframe

Comment: @Batan112, нужно в внести правки в сайт ссылку на который Вы вставляете